# Problem with parsing on selenium, scrolling

Tags: selenium, parsing

there is a problem, I will explain the script of the code.

First, we go to the main page, then the for loop that goes to page 1, scrolls and parses the links to the photo (it doesn’t parse without scrolling), then goes to page 2, and there is already a problem.
It scrolls to the bottom in a second. And I need it to scroll gradually, like on the first page.
I throw the code:

```
driver.get(url=url)

n = 0

urla = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ipsPagination_pageJump").text


for page_number in range(int(urla.split()[3])):
    page_number = page_number + 1
    driver.get(url=url + f"page/{page_number}")
    time.sleep(2)
    imgs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cGalleryPatchwork_image")
    for i in imgs:
        n = n + 500
        driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {n})")
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(i.get_attribute("src"))

driver.quit()
```

I know the code is very bad and not optimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**to scroll** gradually one element by one element you should use the following `execute_script` command `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)`

Code:

```
for page_number in range(int(urla.split()[3])):
    page_number = page_number + 1
    driver.get(url=url + f"page/{page_number}")
    time.sleep(2)
    imgs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "cGalleryPatchwork_image")
    for i in imgs:
        #n = n + 500
        #driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollTo(0, {n})")
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", i)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        print(i.get_attribute("src"))
```